# Error pip install with exit code: 1 (subprocess-exited-with-error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I've been using google colab for doing some projects, but lately i met an issue with installing tfx and tensorflow-model-analysis. Whenever i try to install it always end up with exit code: 1 (subprocess-exited-with-error & metadata-generation-failed).

I tried to upgrade some dependencies, follow some solutions and try with different device, but it didn't solve. Any suggest?

[image: error exit code 1]

expect to solved an error

Comment: *a suggestion*:try updating `setuptools`

Answer (score 1):

You need to Upgrade your versions of `pip`, `setuptools` and `wheel` -

```
pip install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade
pip3 install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade
```

if you don't have pip in your PATH environment variable -

```
python -m pip install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade
python3 -m pip install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade
py -m pip install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade
```